# Getting a user which has only one role in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using ms sql express 2008 and the following is my problem.  In my system there are some users which have two roles '1' and '2' and others which have only one role '2'.  In this stored procedure I just want to get the users who have one role. I want to get a particular user from the system which have only the role of '2'.

The following is my sp:

```
SELECT      tblUsers.user_id, tblUsers.user_username, tblUsers.user_password, tblUsers.user_name, tblUsers.user_surname, tblUsers.user_email
FROM        tblRoles
INNER JOIN  tblUserRole ON tblRoles.role_id = tblUserRole.role_id
INNER JOIN  tblUsers ON tblUserRole.user_id = tblUsers.user_id
WHERE       (tblUserRole.role_id = 2) AND NOT (tblUserRole.role_id = 1)
```

this statement is still getting me the users with two roles as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `group by` along with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT tblUsers.user_id, tblUsers.user_username, 
       tblUsers.user_password, tblUsers.user_name, 
       tblUsers.user_surname, tblUsers.user_email,
       count(1)
  FROM tblRoles INNER JOIN
       tblUserRole ON tblRoles.role_id = tblUserRole.role_id INNER JOIN
       tblUsers ON tblUserRole.user_id = tblUsers.user_id
 GROUP BY tblUsers.user_id, tblUsers.user_username, 
       tblUsers.user_password, tblUsers.user_name, 
       tblUsers.user_surname, tblUsers.user_email
HAVING count(1) = 1
```

Comment: can you please help me understand it.  and when trying to execute the query it is telling me: Column 'tblUsers.user_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  tried also to remove column user_id and keeps telling me the same always with first column in SELECT statement

Comment: 10x for the update worked fine now and I can understand it :)